# Did I described the entities correctly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am studying the topic how to create a web application + link to the database.
Project Spring-Boot + Thymeleaf.
Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "childrens", schema = "public", catalog = "people")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@SelectBeforeUpdate
public class PeopleEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "operation_id")
    private ChildrenEntity сhildrenEntityId;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    //@JoinColumn(name = "blood_group_id")
    private BloodgroupEntity bloodgroupEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "childrens", schema = "public", catalog = "blood_group")
...
public class BloodgroupEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private PeopleEntity peopleEntity;
}
```

TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    id_blood_group BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( pk_people )
)

ALTER TABLE public.people ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cblood_group FOREIGN KEY (id_blood_group) REFERENCES blood_group(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE


CREATE TABLE blood_group (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    id_children BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( pk_blood_group )
)
```

Controller

```
private List<OperationTableEntity> peopleEntityList;
private List<BloodgroupEntity> bloodgroupEntityList;

@GetMapping(value = "/add-product-type")
public String showAddOperation(@ModelAttribute("peopleEntityList") PeopleEntity peopleEntity
         Model model) {
    peopleEntityList = peopleEntityService.getAll();
    bloodgroupEntityList = bloodgroupEntityService.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("peopleEntityList", peopleEntityList);
    model.addAttribute("bloodgroupEntityList", childrenEntityList);
    return "add-people";
 }

@PostMapping(value = "/people/new")
public String createPeople(@ModelAttribute("peopleEntity") PeopleEntity peopleEntity) {
    peopleEntityService.save(peopleEntity);
    return "redirect:/add-product-type";
}
```

I use Thymeleaf on the Web.
File add-people.html:

```html
...
<form id="f-prt-01" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/people/new}" th:object="${peopleEntity}" name="formPrType">
    <div class="form-group mt-1">
        <label for="inputName">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Имя" th:field="*{name}" autofocus required>

        <label for="inputGroupSelect02">группа</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">

            <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02" th:field="*{сhildrenEntityId}">
                <option th:each="bloodgroupTable : ${bloodgroupEntityList}"
                        th:value="${bloodgroupTable.id}"
                        th:text="${bloodgroupTable.name}"/>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone have a look and tell me whether I correctly implemented the code for the tables `PeopleEntity` and `BloodgroupEntity`? I.e., one person can only have one blood group, so the **relationship is OneToOne**. I did it by analogy in training courses. They are really different for everyone.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think you have to properly manage your table first. In normal way BloodGroup is fixed entity and People are various so you have to link BloodGroup object inside People. In addition you're using lombok annotation so before use this initial level you go without it so you get batter idea what the usage of it and what attribute you bind with it. I'll send a link to simple mapping example with read-me soon.

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about those (A, AB, B, 0) blood groups? There are only four from what I remember (adding the Rh+ and Rh- modifiers will give us 8). If that is the case, You might want to change the mapping type. Many people can have the same blood group, so mapping it as @OneToOne is not the best option, since it will require Your JPA provider to create unique blood type records for each associated person. If I were You, I would change that one relationship as following:

```
public class PeopleEntity {
...
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "blood_group_id")
private BloodgroupEntity bloodgroupEntityId;
}
```

If you want to make it bidirectional (which is not mandatory), but gives you an access to an entity from both sides of the relationship you can add following piece to Your blood group entity:

```
public class BloodgroupEntity {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bloodgroupEntityId")
    private Set<PeopleEntity> people = new HashSet<>();
```

If you decide to go for bidirectional, you have to remember that You need to cater for keeping both sides of the association in sync, meaning that you need extra methods in your classes.

If I am mistaken and there you are creating some medical application, wherein each blood group is unique and assigned to only one person in the world, then ok @OneToOne is a good option, although you can enhance it by using @MapsId.

If you are just studying JPA and Hibernate in general, keep in mind that:

1. Collections association is optional - you can substitute all of that with sql queries or with the use of JPA Query interface(to speed things up). If you compose the collection mapping in a wrong way it can cause real performance issues with large amount of data.
2. I would recommend focusing on transactions and state management to begin with, which will help you understand how the ORM works with entities. It will help you understand errors that can occur along the way, when you map collections (LazyInitializationException for example) and how to avoid that;
3. When studying collections mappings - I would advise to tackle them one by one, starting from the most common one, which is I guess @ManyToOne (then tackle bidirectional mapping of @OneToMany). Play with different fetch types, different cascade options. Then @OneToOne and @ManyToMany

Comment: I'm just learning JPA and Hibernate. if i redo to ManyToOne. Do I need to fix the blood_group table in the database? I. e. I need to leave this field: id_blood_group BIGINT NOT NULL. And do i need a foreign key fk_cblood_group in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This article says that it is better not to use Set:
https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/